# what is the suitable resources for 500 requests per second?

Tags: performance, load-testing, traffic

the point that every request need some processing. I want to know if my resources enough or I have to upgrade it, or may be I have to test my code and optimize it.
My resources :
4 CPU and 8G ram.
Any outlines, test tools will be appreciated.

Comment: Without further information, your question is meaningless. Is your request html? PHP? ASP? MySql request? What kind of connection are you running (since that's usually the bottleneck)? How big/detailed is the request? etc

Comment: expected 500 request for pages, And I'm using php-laravel.
Now up to 100 database connection and will be up to 10X.
Thanks for your interest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are serving a static small page - you will be able to serve hundreds of thousands requests per second on that hardware. If you have very "heavy" page which requires lots of server-side processing - it can be just few concurrent users.

I would recommend the following:

1. Get the load testing tool, for example see [Open Source Load Testing Tools: Which One Should You Use? article for comparison](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/open-source-load-testing-tools-which-one-should-you-use).
2. Set it up to replicate real users as close as possible (headers, cookies, cache, AJAX requests, etc.), virtual users should follow main application use cases
3. Start with 1-2 virtual users and double check everything works as expected
4. Gradually increase the load to anticipated number of users and observe system behaviour and main metrics like response time, number of transactions per second, etc. If you are happy with the results - that's it. If not - identify the bottleneck (which is not necessarily your code) and fix it. Repeat. Use [profiling tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming)) to inspect your code and identify the most resources consuming parts. Refactor. Repeat.
5. You can also consider increasing load until your application starts breaking to see what fails first, will the system recover when the load gets back to normal, etc.

Comment: The idea behind the web services on the website. The web services needs some processing and database connections up to 100 connections per second and expected to be 10X.
Thanks alot for your interest and your time, I'm going to follow the links you mentioned above.